# How can watchtower avoid upgrading replicas at the same time

Tags: watchtower

My web app has redundancy for high availability. How shall I configure watchtower to avoid upgrading the docker containers simultaneously, which will shut the entire site down?

Is there any solution to configure a delay for each replica so that the upgrading won't happen at the same time?